# ¿Cómo obtener el ID de un input si estoy usando la librería jquery.multifield.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Buen día a todos, estoy intentando obtener el `id` de un `input` dinámico, con el fin de que cuando haga un keyup, en ese input que estoy tecleando me muestre su valor que tecleé.
Estoy usando la librería jquery.multifield.js.
Esta librería me funciona muy bien a la hora de duplicar los campos de mi formulario, pero ahora me surgió un problema, no puedo obtener el `id` de cada input. Lo intenté con obtenerlo desde su id, pero sólo me obtiene el primero de todos, es decir, si tengo 3 `input` duplicados solo me regresa el `id` del primero, y cada vez que hago un `keyup` a todos los `input` duplicados les da el mismo valor y no de los 2 restantes.
Mi formulario es el siguiente:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="submitForm">
    <div class="grillaCotizacion1">
        <div class="form-item">
            <input type="text" name="nombreCliente" autocomplete="off" required class="cotizacion">
            <label for="precio">Nombre completo: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-item">
            <input type="text" name="telefono" autocomplete="off" required class="cotizacion">
            <label for="total">Teléfono:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-item">
            <input type="text" name="correo" autocomplete="off" required class="cotizacion">
            <label for="correo">correo:</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grillaCotizacion2">
        <div class="form-item">
            <input type="text" name="direccion" autocomplete="off" required class="cotizacion">
            <label for="direccion">dirección:</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="example-2">
        <div class="form-item">
            <button type="button" id="btnAdd-2" class="btnAdd">Agregar más campos</button>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class="grillaCotizacion3">
                <div class="form-item">
                    <input type="text" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" autocomplete="off" required class="cotizacion" onkeyup="mostrar()"> <!-- quiero obtener el id de este input -->
                    <label for="cantidad">cantidad:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item">
                    <textarea name="descripcion[]" class="cotizacion"></textarea>
                    <label for="descripcion">descripcion:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item">
                    <input type="text" name="factor[]" autocomplete="off" required class="cotizacion">
                    <label for="factor">factor:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item">
                    <textarea name="contenido[]" class="cotizacion"></textarea>
                    <label for="contenido">contenido:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item">
                    <input type="text" name="precioUnitario[]" id="precioUnitario" autocomplete="off" required class="cotizacion">
                    <label for="precio_unitario">p.unitario:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item">
                    <input type="text" name="subtotal[]" id="subtotal" autocomplete="off" required class="cotizacion">
                    <label for="subtotal" id="subtotal">subtotal</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnRemove">Eliminar</button>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end class="grillaCotizacion3"-->
        </div> <!-- end class="group"-->
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <button type="submit" class="btnSuccess">Hacer cotización</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Y mi código javascript para obtener el id de la caja "cantidad" es el siguiente:

```
<script>
    function mostrar() {
        let inputValue = $("#cantidad").val();
        alert(inputValue);
    }
</script>
```

Adjunto una imagen de las cajas que se duplican pero que no tienen su id único.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté hacerlo con `attr` y `data` pero no logro obtener el valor de cada `input` que se duplique.
¿Podrían asesorarme en cómo obtener el valor de cada input que se duplique?
De antemano agradezco que hayan leído hasta aquí.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
function mostrar(el) {
    let inputValue = el.value;
    alert(inputValue);
}
```

y en la llamada al keyup pon esto:

```
onkeyup="mostrar(this)"
```

Y ya diras si te funciona

Comment: Recorre todas las cajas de texto, pero al hacer keyup en una caja, me muestra todos los valores de las cajas y no de la caja en la que estoy haciendo keyup.

Comment: @HermannBD recarga la página y prueba mi respuesta de nuevo a ver si ahora si

Comment: Hice un script de jquery con estos datos: $("#cantidad").on('keyup', function(e) {
                console.log("algo");
            }); //Aún así no me obtiene el valor del input en donde estoy haciendo keyup, solo en la primera caja muestra le mensaje

Comment: El problema que tiene tu jquery es que eso que usas para duplicar seguramente esta duplicando los id tambien, y por norma un `id` deberia ser único (por eso mi anterior solución fue usando name y no id)... ¿has probado mi nuevo código?

Comment: Estoy probando tu código, en unos momentos lo implementaré para hacer una function con jquery en una caja

Comment: Necesito tu consejo, ¿dónde es mejor? Mandar a llamar al método mostrar directamente en la caja input? ó hacer una function con jquery al hacer un keyup.

Comment: Bueno, dicen que hemos de evitar al máximo los eventos onXXXX= en los html y que lo hagamos siempre mediante `addEventListener` (en javascript puro) o bien el `.on` en jquery, para separar mejor lo que seria estructura (html) de acciones interactivas (js) u otras cosas (php, mysql)... pero todo es opinable

Comment: mi consejo es que decidas tu :-)